# onStartJob method of JobService executes as soon as job is scheduled

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

Working on an android app, I am using `FirebaseJobDispatcher` to run a job after every 1 minute.

**Problem**

As soon as i run the app, job executes and then executes after every 1 minute.

**Question**

Why is `onStartJob` called immediately when the job is scheduled? Why is it not waiting 1 minute before executing? What am i doing wrong?

**Code**

```
public static void scheduleReminders(Context context) {

   Driver driver = new GooglePlayDriver(context);
   FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(driver);

   Job job = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                    .setService(ReminderJobService.class)
                    .setTag(JOB_TAG)
                    .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
                    .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                    .setRecurring(true)
                    .setReplaceCurrent(true)
                    .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
                    .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(60, 65))
                    .build();

   dispatcher.mustSchedule(job);
}
```

`scheduleReminders` function is called from `onCreate` method of the main activity.

Comment: AFAICT, the `executionWindow()` is merely a hint. The underlying engine being used, based on the driver, may not support all possible values.

Answer (score 0):

The source code of `Trigger` contains:

```
  /**
   * Creates a new ExecutionWindow based on the provided time interval.
   *
   * @param windowStart The earliest time (in seconds) the job should be considered eligible to run.
   *     Calculated from when the job was scheduled (for new jobs) or last run (for recurring jobs).
   * @param windowEnd The latest time (in seconds) the job should be run in an ideal world.
   *     Calculated in the same way as {@code windowStart}.
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the provided parameters are too restrictive.
   */
```

Since you are scheduling a recurring job (`.setRecurring(true)`), the window start time will be since the job was last run, which may cause issues if you're *rescheduling* a job from a minute ago with no changes, although `setReplaceCurrent(true)` should avoid the problem.

The more likely cause (as @CommonsWare said) is these triggers *aren't* perfectly accurate, they're when you'd like the OS to schedule your job, not when it'll actually run. The `in an ideal world` phrase in the comment above is key!

A way to increase the likelihood of execution happening at the correct time is to increase the window of opportunity the OS has, e.g 50 & 100 seconds instead of 60 & 65. Alternatively if you need something at an exact time, perhaps an Alarm is a better approach.